# Android App permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I just published my app and I do have a problem with my app permissions

My app uses some extra permissions like Identity ( find accounts on the device ) and Location (approximate location (network-based).

I haven't include any of those in my manifest xml

I would like to know why I do see those and how to get them off my app

Permissions in my App

[image]

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name_short">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

My libraries that I'm use (build.gradle) :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
```

libs/commons-io-2.4 << this is Apache Commons Library

Comment: Are you using any libraries that may require those permissions? Can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: @JosephRoque I just posted them

Comment: See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html) where I go into more detail on how to try to fix things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What parts of the play-services are you using? This is most likely causing the problems. You're compiling location, gcm, etc. APIs all into your app when you most likely only want ads. Try replacing the line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` in your build.gradle with:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

If you need other APIs, find them in [this list](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and only add the ones you're using.

Comment: solved my problem , also I have used the src code of my .jar library for the specific classes I need to use instead of using the whole jar package.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your project's dependencies. Android library projects can publish manifests. Those manifests can have `<uses-permission>` elements in them it will blend with the ones from your manifest and those of other libraries that you are using to build the project, and all of them will be requested by your app.
Here's [blog post about this to follow up](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html).